# How to add additional scrape config to Prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I want to add an additional scrape config into Prometheus. I have followed the below method.

https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/blob/main/Documentation/additional-scrape-config.md

First, created a file prometheus-additional.yaml and added the new config

```
- job_name: "prometheus"
  static_configs:
  - targets: ["localhost:9090"]
```

Secondly, created a secret out of it.

```
kubectl create secret generic additional-scrape-configs --from-file=prometheus-additional.yaml --dry-run -oyaml > additional-scrape-configs.yaml
```

Then created the secret using the below command

```
kubectl apply -f additional-scrape-configs.yaml -n monitoring
```

Then in the above link it says

**"Finally, reference this additional configuration in your prometheus.yaml CRD."**

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: Prometheus
metadata:
  name: prometheus
  labels:
    prometheus: prometheus
spec:
  replicas: 2
  serviceAccountName: prometheus
  serviceMonitorSelector:
    matchLabels:
      team: frontend
  additionalScrapeConfigs:
    name: additional-scrape-configs
    key: prometheus-additional.yaml
```

Where I can find the above? Do I need to create a new CRD? Can't I update the existing running deployment?

Comment: Hello @Container-Man, I m working on exactly the same feature (adding additional scrape configs).  The new configuration can be found on the Prometheus UI->Menu Status-> configuration.
I m still not able to see the Prometheus Configuration appended with the additional scrape configs (from secrets). I would really appreciate it if you share with me how you fix it on your end. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

This is somehow wrong in the Documentation, you have to use additionalScrapeConfigs**Secret**:

```
  additionalScrapeConfigsSecret:
    enabled: true
    name: additional-scrape-configs
    key: prometheus-additional.yaml
```

Else you get the error `cannot unmarshal !!map into []yaml.MapSlice`

Here is a better documentation:
https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/blob/8b45bdbdabd9b54766c4beb3c562b766b268a034/charts/kube-prometheus-stack/values.yaml#L2691

According to this, you could add scrape configs without packaging into a secret like this:

```
additionalScrapeConfigs: |
  - job_name: "prometheus"
  static_configs:
  - targets: ["localhost:9090"]
```

Answer (score 0):

That document applies to prometheus-operator. If you have deployed it, you should have your *Prometheus* CRD:

```
kubectl get prometheus -n monitoring
```

Then you can edit the Prometheus exactly as stated in above: adding *additionalScrapeConfigs* key in the spec. (after adding a secret)

After editing, new scrape configs will be reloaded and applied automatically (conf-reloaders).